# Copy chart from Calc spreadsheet to Writer document without linking in Libreoffice?

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-writer

I've copied a chart in one of my Libreoffice 3.4.3 Calc spreadsheets into a Writer document in Mac OS X 10.6.8. However, I've noticed that the chart in the Writer document is linked to the one in the spreadsheet.

Is there a way to copy the chart so that it can exist independently in the Writer text document, so that if the file is moved to another computer, the chart will retain its integrity???

I tried Paste Special, but I am only given options to paste as "Star Object Descriptor" or "GDI metafile", with not option of pasting "directly", nor an option to paste as image. What should I do?

P.S. Not sure if this matters, but I'd also like to be sure that if I save the text document as a M$ Word document, it will still open and view correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you used Copy and Paste, use Paste Special (assuming that the Mac OS X functions are similar to the programs on Windows) and paste the chart directly rather than as a link.  One of the Paste Special options should do the trick.

Don't be surprised if the entire Calc is embedded.  If you don't want that, you may need to paste the chart as a graphic image.

Comment: I tried Paste Special, but I am only given options to paste as "Star Object Descriptor" or "GDI metafile", with not option of pasting "directly", nor an option to paste as image. What should I do? Thanks! (will append this to original post).

Comment: Try the GDI Metafile.  That should work fine.  It will be the chart and nothing about its connection to data will be preserved, but it sounds like you want the chart only.

Comment: "Paste special" -> "Formatted text" is doing the trick as outlined [elsewhere](http://askubuntu.com/q/40126/20334)